# Telegram bot api inlineKeyboard not worked

Tags: node.js, telegram-bot

I use [node_telegram_bot_api](https://github.com/yagop/node-telegram-bot-api) for my Telegram bot. I create an inline keyboard buttons :

```
var bot = new loader.Bot(config.botToken,{polling:true});
var options = {
        reply_markup: JSON.stringify({
            inline_keyboard: [
                [{text: 'Some button text 1', callback_data: '1'}], // Clicking will send "1"
                [{text: 'Some button text 2', callback_data: '2'}], // Clicking will send "2"
                [{text: 'Some button text 3', callback_data: '3'}]  // Clicking will send "3"
            ]
        })
    };

    bot.sendMessage(msg.from.id, "Click a button to display data", options);
```

And I told a callback_query function for listen to click the buttons:

```
bot.on('callback_query', function(msg) {
    var user = msg.from.id;
    var data = msg.data;
    bot.sendMessage(msg.from.id, "You clicked button with data '"+ data +"'");
});
```

After clicking on the buttons this function is not implemented.
Can you help me?

Comment: I think you don't need JSON.stringify. Anyway, this will not fix your problem as it appears to work even if not needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This test woks for me:

https://ide.c9.io/jlvaquero/test

Try to compare it with your project. My 2 cents it is your node_telegram_bot_api version.

Comment: I can't access to `c9`, can you put your code in `jsbin.com`?

Comment: Did you discover your issue? Can you post it and the fix done for future references to other people with similar problems, please?